# Microsoft update- .NET Framework- Vulnerability Mangement

Tags: .net, security, patch, system-administration

The version of the Mscorlib.dll file (in .NET) has been updated from

```
4.7.4038.0 to 4.8.4645.0(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Mscorlib.dll
```

has version:

```
4.7.4038.0-> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Mscorlib.dll
```

has version:

```
4.8.4645.0):
```

Is it possible without KB update?`

Is there a possibility for .NET Framework to upgrade from `4.7.4038.0 to 4.8.4645.0` without KB update?

Comment: 4.8 has been released for over 4 years now, so skipping the prerequisite and forcing the installation might end up in an unstable system.